# Eyes won't show correctly (Overlapping?) (Transparency Issue?)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, node-editor, transparency

I have these eyes & there are eyeballs & eyes. The eyeballs are meant to be transparent, & there are until I add the eye? So the black eyes themselves are transparent but once I add the white it just does that as shown in picture 2, so I need the eyes to show.

[image] 
[image]

These are the nodes, the 1st one is the eye & the second one is the actual eyeball.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eevee treats transparent objects differently than Cycles. They are sorted from front-to-back per object and do not receive any screen space effects.

This is fast and works fine for many cases, but it is only approximate and gives incorrect results for some object shapes. For more accurate results, enable Alpha Hashed transparency in the material. With a sufficient number of samples to resolve the noise this gives accurate transparency.