# Image as plane layering problem

Tags: image, eevee-render-engine

I've got this problem with layered planes where planes behind are showing through the top ones.

Tried spacing them further apart but that didn't fix the problem since I plan to make a lot of these for foliage so I can't do that. When spaced really far apart, the problem does not happen, but this is not viable in my use case.

Made a video to illustrate the problem so please take a look at the link below.

https://youtu.be/LGGhv192yzo

Comment: I am using Eevee yes.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160389/pngs-in-distance-appear-to-overlap-foreground-pngs-when-viewed-at-different-angl

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143525/eyes-wont-show-correctly-overlapping-transparency-issue/144813#144813

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182646/odd-transparency-or-normal-issues/182651#182651

Comment: Swapping blendmode from alpha blend to alpha clip fixed it so I will keep this in mind in the future, thank you.

Comment: Please write an answer in the answers section. Other users with the same issue can learn from your experience